# can we use valdr.addConstraint and addValidator function outside the config block ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, valdr

i am newly using valdr in angualrjs . i m making validation directive using valdr for my application. i don't want to write addconstaints and addvalidator functions with json inside app.config file. i want to write that part inside the directive only ? can anyone solve this problem...?

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['valdr']);

app.config(function (valdrProvider) {
    valdrProvider.addConstraints({
        'Person': {
            'firstname':
                {
                    'size': {
                        'min': 3,
                        'max': 12,
                        'message':'firstname should be between 3 to 12 '
                    },
                    'required': {
                        'message': 'This field is required.'
                    }
                },
            'firstName':
                {
                    'customValidator': {
                        'message': 'First name must be Hanueli.'
                    }
                }
        }
    });
});

app.directive('info', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'tmpl.html',
        require: '^?valdrProvider',
        link: function ($scope, valdrProvider) {
            $scope.Person = {};
            $scope.$watch(valdrProvider.getConstraints, function (newContraints) {
                $scope.constraints = newContraints;
            })
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how that could be useful but you can of course call `valdrProvider.addConstraints()` whenever you see fit. In `link: function ($scope, valdrProvider)` you get access to the provider.

Comment: thank you sir for your valuable feedback .. but i tried it not working. if you some other way plz let me know..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the naming. Angular provides two ways to configure providers.
1. during the configuration phase - here you have to append the "Provider" suffix.
2. during runtime - here you just get the service.

Change `valdrProvider` to `valdr` and you can addConstraints in your service/controller